# Child Theme CSS not showing at all

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have a child theme that is not showing my CSS changes at all. When I inspect element, the changes don't show in the explorer window. I look in the head and the child theme style is not enqueuing.

Child functions.php:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style');
function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Child style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Jevelin Child
Description: Child theme for Jevelin theme
Author: Shufflehound
Author URI: http://shufflehound.com
Template: jevelin
Text Domain: jevelin-child
*/

/* Add your custom CSS below */
```

I have no idea what the culprit could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this instead of what you are using. This will definitely work.

```
 <?php
       function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

**For more details on configuring Child themes in WordPress please refer to this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).**